# GridWorld, grid not extending

Tags: java, gridworld

Basically I made I class to extend the grid to 11 by 11, the constructor is being called however its not changing the grid. Any input or information on why would be greatly appreciated. I've posted my code below:

```
import info.gridworld.actor.*;
import info.gridworld.grid.BoundedGrid;

public class ChangeGrid extends ActorWorld{

private static final int SIZEROW = 11;
private static final int SIZECOL = 11;

public ChangeGrid()
{
    super(new BoundedGrid<Actor>(SIZEROW, SIZECOL));
    System.out.println("test");
}

}


import info.gridworld.actor.Bug;
public class XBug extends Bug {
    /**
     * A <code>BoxBug</code> traces out a square "box" of a given size. <br />
     * The implementation of this class is testable on the AP CS A and AB exams.
     */

        private int steps;
        private int sideLength;
        private int x = 0;

        private static ChangeGrid object = new ChangeGrid();


        /**
         * Constructs a box bug that traces a square of a given side length
         * @param length the side length
         */
        public XBug(int length)
        {
            steps = 0;
            sideLength = length;
        }

        /**
         * Moves to the next location of the square.
         */
        public void act()
        {
            if (steps < sideLength && canMove())
            {
                if(x==0)
                {
                    turn();
                }
                move();
                steps++;
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                turn();

                steps = 0;
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Your `XBug` constructor sets two ints. That's it. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The `XBug` class seems to be fairly unrelated to the actual question. However, some code that *might* be relevant seems to be missing. E.g. where and how `ChangeGrid` is used, or whether the "test" is printed and indicates that your modified constructur is actually called...

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor is not being called when you create the world. You are calling it inside of an `Actors` class, then you don't even call the `.show()` method. You just need to change your runner class to call `ChangeWorld` instead of `ActorWorld`.

Here's an example for your code.

```
    public class Runner 
    {
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            ChangeWorld world = new ChangeWorld();
            XBug bug = new XBug();

            world.add(bug);

            world.show();
        }
    }
```